# Phalcon REST Api multi-module

Tags: php, api, rest, phalcon

I'm building a multi module using Phalcon. I have an Application named frontend and a REST API in micro application. But I have a question about the way to create my rest api. It's necessary to use a micro app in multi module ? Because I can't define the routes for my rest api because it has't controller, just an index.php. Should I create my rest api in a controller class and remove the index.php ?

Here is my architecture.

```
multiple/
├── common
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── config.php
│   │   ├── modules.php
│   │   └── services.php
│   ├── library
│   │   └── Elements.php
│   │   └── Tools.php
│   │   └── PhpMailer.php
│   ├── models
│   │   └── User.php
├── modules
│   ├── frontend
│   │   ├── Module.php
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   ├── ControllerBase.php
│   │   │   └── IndexController.php
│   │   ├── plugins
│   │   │   └── SecurityPlugin.php
│   │   │   └── NotFoundPlugin.php
│   │   ├── cache
│   │   │   └── cache1.php
│   │   │   └── cache2.php
│   │   └── views
│   │       ├── index
│   │       │   └── index.phtml
│   │       └── index.phtml
│   │
│   └── api
│       └── index.php
│       └── Module.php
│       
├── .htaccess
├── index.html
└── public
    └── index.php
    └── .htaccess
```